# How to create scrollable linear layout in Android Studio?

Tags: xml, android-studio, layout

I would like to create a layout like the following image,

[image]

and it is my code,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/dynamic_linear_layout"
    android:weightSum="2"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        >
        <FrameLayout
            android:background="@color/lb_grey"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/container1"
            android:layout_weight="1">

        </FrameLayout>
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/container2"
            android:layout_weight="1">

        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/container3"
            android:layout_weight="1">

        </FrameLayout>
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/container4"
            android:layout_weight="1">

        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >
        <FrameLayout
            android:background="#FF1122"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/container5"
            android:layout_weight="1">

        </FrameLayout>
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/container6"
            android:layout_weight="1">

        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

As you can see there are 6 user containers in the XML layout and I would like to see just 4 users on the screen like the image. When I scroll the menu I should be able to see the other 2 users but in my code I cant scroll and don't see the other 2 users never. 
Do you have any idea about it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a Nested Scrollview

Comment: I changed scroll view with nested scroll view but nothing changed.